# How to use a callback function in the Ajax Loaded Datatable?

Tags: jquery, callback, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../ajax/sources/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

In above example when sAjaxSource loads the data into datatable i want to have a callback function which is called after the data load, What is the proper way of doing it.

The above given solution does not answers my problem. I do not want to do anything with the data from the datatable, I just want to wait till the data has loaded and then use that data to update another div on my DOM.

Comment: @undefined i have read the documentation and tried few things couldnt get a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example for dataloaded from server callback function. You can modify the data as well using the same function.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Call back functions here: [Datatable Callback functions](http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks)

Comment: Whay do not post an fnCallback() method as example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  "`fnServerData`":  for that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        ........
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {

            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 

            fnCallback(json)
        } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)